# How to run jython script from RAD using credentials from properties file?

Tags: websphere, jython, wsadmin, ibm-rad

According to documentation: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rsawshlp/v7r5m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.ws.ast.jythontools.doc%2Ftopics%2Ftjythondebug.html to run jython script with credentials "As defined in soap.client.props or sas.client.props file":

> The sas.client.props and the soap.client.props files are located in
>   the properties directory for each WebSphere Application Server
>   profile, for example x:/profilePath/properties

I've created file:

> C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer85\properties\soap.client.props

The next part is about setting `com.ibm.CORBA` and `com.ibm.SOAP` properties. Because it is not written, which of them are used as credentials, I've set both:

```
com.ibm.CORBA.loginUserid=user 
com.ibm.CORBA.loginPassword=pass
com.ibm.CORBA.loginSource=properties
com.ibm.SOAP.securityEnabled=true
com.ibm.SOAP.loginUserid=user
com.ibm.SOAP.loginPassword=pass
```

But I can't run the script on WebSphere:

> WASX7246E: Cannot establish "SOAP" connection to host "localhost"
>   because of an authentication failure. Ensure that user and password
>   are correct on the command line or in a properties file.

I'm using IBM RAD 9.0 and WebSphere 8.5

What I'm doing wrong? I've done everything as I've understood from cited documentation, but it's very laconical and unprecise for me.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the connector being used (SOAP or RMI), wsadmin retrieves credentials from either soap.client.props or sas.client.props. In your case the connector is SOAP (that's what the error message suggests), so you have to edit two lines in soap.client.props:

```
com.ibm.SOAP.loginUserid=...
com.ibm.SOAP.loginPassword=...
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've done, as described in question, the problem is that I get that error message, theoretically doing everything as described.